# #Error in the calculated value in SSRS output

Tags: reporting-services, calculated-columns

I am new to SSRS and am using 2017 version to make some paginated reports in SSRS with SAP HANA as DS.
I have data which looks like:

```
SO     TYPE LABEL    Amount  CY Sales
A010    10  Sales    2023       
A020    20  Total    100        
A030    20  Labour   400        
A040    30  Shipping   0
```

Here CY is the CY and Sales are calculated fields where:

```
CY = IIF(Fields!SO.Values="A020" and Fields!TYPE.Value=20 , Fields!Amount.Value,0)

Sales = Sum(Fields!CY.Values)
```

Now when I use the above expression I get result for Sales as `#Error` and CY as `NaN`.

The data type for both the expressions is default.

Can anyone help me so that I can get values for CY and Sales.

Comment: On the surface of it, it looks ok. May be SSRS is having trouble evaluating two data types in your CY expression. How about you cast your TYPE Field and see if it works? something like and CSTR(Fields!TYPE.Value) = "20". Once you fix your CY, then Sales should be find as it depends on CY

Comment: Your sales expression has an extra s, its Sum(Fields!CY.Values) instead of Sum(Fields!CY.Value)

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should be:
= Sum(Fields!CY.Values)